# Find a basis $B$ for the domain of $T$ such that the matrix for $T$ relative to $B$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis $B$ for the domain of $T$ such that the matrix for $T$ relative to $B$ is diagonal.

$$T: R^2 \to R^2: T(x, y) = (6x + 3y, 2x + y).$$

I found the eigenvalues to be $0$ and $7$. I found the eigenvectors to be $(3,1)$ and $(-0.5,1)$.

I am not sure how to find a basis.

Comment: The eigenvectors are a basis, relative to which the matrix is diagonal (with eigenvalue entries)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So then the basis is (3,1)(-0.5,1)

Comment: That is correct